# Resolving conflict between transitive dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have a pom.xml where i've got hadoop-core dependency as provided

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I add cfg4j as compile time dependency

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.cfg4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>cfg4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.cfg4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>cfg4j-consul</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

I've got an exception "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.someMethod". I've investigated the problem and find out that the problem is from hadoop and cfg4j-consul. Hadoop core depends to jersey-core and cfg4j depends on cxf. Both declared javax.ws.rs as dependecy so the problem is that jersey has version 1.1 and cxf has 2.0.2. Hadoop dependency is provided, cause it's needed by Flink (framework) and it's in the lib folder. I can't just upgrade it or remove it, nor add it as compile time and exclude the lib. Even I was able to do it, I have no guarantees that hadoop will work as expected. I guess shading doesn't fix the problem cause it's not with cfg4j but one of the dependency of his dependency.
Is there way to resolve the conflict? Does gradle has it's onw ways to fix such issue?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

- Shading: A bit more difficult as you say because this a transitive dependency, but I would have a look a Maven shade plugin and it would still be possible to declare the dependency directly if necessary.
- Don't use the dependency and try to find some other library or solution for your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps, here is the source: https://reflectoring.io/nosuchmethod/
Your issue has nothing to do with the choice between Mavern and Gradle, switching therefor will not help.

**Fixing a NoSuchMethodError**
There are a lot of different flavors of `NoSuchMethodErrors`, but they all boil down to the fact that the compile time classpath differs from the runtime classpath.

The following steps will help to pinpoint the problem:

**Step 1:** Find Out Where the Class Comes From
First, we need to find out where the class containing the method in question comes from. We find this information in the error message of the `NoSuchMethodError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  io.reflectoring.nosuchmethod.Service.sayHello(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Now, we can search the web or within the IDE to find out which JAR file contains this class. In the case above, we can see that it’s the Service class from our own codebase and not a class from another library.

If we have trouble finding the JAR file of the class, we can add the Java option -verbose:class when running our application. This will cause Java to print out all classes and the JARs they have been loaded from:

```
[Loaded io.reflectoring.nosuchmethod.Service from file:
  /C:/daten/workspaces/code-examples2/patterns/build/libs/java-1.0.jar]
```

**Step 2:** Find Out Who Calls the Class
Next, we want find out where the method is being called. This information is available in the first element of the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  io.reflectoring.nosuchmethod.Service.sayHello(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  at io.reflectoring.nosuchmethod.ProvokeNoSuchMethodError.main(ProvokeNoSuchMethodError.java:7)
```

Here, the class `ProvokeNoSuchMethodError` tries to call a method that does not exist at runtime. We should now find out which library this file belongs to.

**Step 3**: Check the Versions
Now that we know where the `NoSuchMethodError` is provoked and what method is missing, we can act.

We should now list all of our project dependencies.

In Gradle, we can call:

./gradlew dependencies > dependencies.txt
If we’re using Maven, a similiar result can be achieved with:

mvn dependency:list > dependencies.txt`
In this file, we can search for the libraries that contain the class with the missing method and the class that tries to call this method.

Usually we’ll find an output like this somewhere:

```
\--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE
|     \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE -> 5.0.8.RELEASE
```

The above means that the spring-retry library depends on spring-core in version 4.3.13, but some other library also depends on spring-core in version 5.0.8 and overrules the dependency version.

We can now search our dependencies.txt file for 5.0.8.RELEASE to find out which library introduces the dependency to this version.

**Finally**, we need to decide which of the two versions we actually need to satisfy both dependencies. Usually, this is the newer version since most frameworks are backwards compatible to some point. However, it can be the other way around or we might even not be able to resolve the conflict at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answere, but I already tried all those steps and the result is that javax.ws.rs is part of hadoop-core (provided dependency, alreadey in the classpath) and cfg4j (compile dependency in my code) and the one that doesn't work is cfg4j, I can't just exclude the dependency, it will still not work and can't update the hadoop dependency since it's provided